# Display User Meta in Users.php column

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

In WordPress user's profile I have custom user meta setup `_yith_wcact_user_ban`

The custom field is a true / false checkbox.

I have added the necessary code to functions.php that adds this custom user meta to display in columns of users.php.

However, how do you return the value to display `Verfied` or `Unauthorised` in the column?

_yith_wcact_user_ban = true = Unauthorised

_yith_wcact_user_ban = false = Verfied

```
function add_custom_column_name($columns) {
    $columns['columns_array_name'] = 'Verification';
    return $columns;
}
function show_custom_column_values($value, $column_name, $user_id) {
    if ( 'columns_array_name' == $column_name )
        return get_user_meta( $user_id, '_yith_wcact_user_ban', true );
return('Unauthorised');
}

add_filter('manage_users_columns', 'add_custom_column_name');
add_action('manage_users_custom_column', 'show_custom_column_values', 10, 3);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`manage_users_custom_column` is a filter hook, not an action hook. try below code.

```
function add_custom_column_name($columns) {
    $columns['verification'] = 'Verification';
    return $columns;
}
function show_custom_column_values($value, $column_name, $user_id) {
    if ( 'verification' == $column_name ){
        if( get_user_meta( $user_id, '_yith_wcact_user_ban', true ) ){
            return "Unauthorised";
        }else{
            return "Verfied";
        }
    }
    return $value;
}

add_filter('manage_users_columns', 'add_custom_column_name');
add_filter('manage_users_custom_column', 'show_custom_column_values', 10, 3);
```

**Tested and works.**

[image]